Application Plugin Exception using version catalog
Within my libs.version.toml (version catalog) I have application plugin defined like this:
[versions]
agp = "7.4.2"
kotlin = "2.0.10"

[plugins]
androidApplication = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }

I'm using multiple modules within my application but this plugin is defined only inside :app module.
build.gradle (Module :app)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroid)
    id('kotlin-kapt')
    id('androidx.navigation.safeargs')
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.serialization)
}

android {
    compileSdk 34
    ....
}

I'm getting this error:
Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.4.2', apply: false]
> The request for this plugin could not be satisfied because the plugin is already on the classpath with an unknown version, so compatibility cannot be checked.


check the Gradle version in gradle-wrapper.properties and check this link  for Android studio version and Gradle version and Plugin version compatiblity.
There is a second way that i use it. create a new project in Android stodio and check version of Gradle and Plugin version to use in downloaded project.
I hope it is useful.

Gradle version is fine. I just tested it with Gradle 8.0 and AGP 8.0 and same error.
